# Android - clipChildren on scrollview with fixed width not working

Tags: android

i have a question about getting clipChildren. I have a HorizontalScrollView with fixed width and want to show the children which are out of bounds. The ScrollView has the fixed width of one of the rectangles. My problem is that I can only see the first rectangle but I want to see both. So this is what it's currently looking:

[image: current]

And this is what I want:

[image: want]

I thought that clipChildren is solving that. Its important that the ScrollView has the fixed width cause of a behaviour what I want. Here my code:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent">


    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollview"
        android:layout_width="210dp"
        android:layout_height="190dp"
        android:scrollbars="none"
        android:clipChildren="false"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:paddingStart="28dp"
            android:paddingEnd="0dp" />

    </HorizontalScrollView>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

I add the views programmatically to the scrollview. So nothing special here. Just:

```
content.addView(childView);
```

As asked in the comments here the code how I get childView and how its structure:

```
final CarouselView childView = new CarouselView(context);
```

layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="210dp"
    android:layout_height="180dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">
<!-- content -->
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: `content` is your `ScrollView` or your `LinearLayout`? I think you are adding children to the `LinearLayout`, not to the `ScrollView`

Comment: Yeah but I have too. HorionztalScrollView can only have on direct child. Otherwise you get the following error:     java.lang.IllegalStateException: HorizontalScrollView can host only one direct child

Comment: I just do a test and it's working for me. I'm adding an image. The new image is added on the right side of the previous one. Can you share how are creating your new object? Are you trying to specify the position od the new object?

Comment: @Ferran I updated my question. As I understand LinearLayout correctly it will automatically position their children horizontallly. Maybe you can give me your test code to comparsion or testing?

Comment: Yes, I was just writing that answer like yours.

Comment: Sorry it was like a few minutes before your answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to add this to the parent layout:

```
android:clipChildren="false"
android:clipToPadding="false"
```

The parent has to be changed from:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent">
```

to:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:clipChildren="false"
    android:clipToPadding="false" 
    android:layout_width="match_parent">
```